# The sync time between the frontpage and the newest question list is different

Tags: discussion, questions, homepage

Questions seem to appear on the front page about 1 or 2 minutes sooner than they appear on the newest question list.

This would not bother me at all if it was the other way around and I don't know if it the cache at work and you can't change it, but I would like to hear some notion from the SO team about this.

Since it's an advantage to those that monitor the fast updating frontpage for questions with a low answer count and recent timestamp.

I'm not tagging this as a bug since it's just they way the system has worked.

Comment: I hope they fix that since I always hang out on the questions page.